# Java API for encrypting / decrypting pdf files

Tags: java, pdf, encryption

I need to encrypt and decrypt pdf files. Is there a free or low cost Java API that does that ? Basically I need to hide files from normal users. Any other suggestion on achieving that programatically ?

Thanks,
Deep

Comment: how do you plan to show them to "abnormal" users? They should bring their private keys (possibly smart cards) with them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [iText](http://itextpdf.com/):

```
  // Assuming you provide the following yourself:
  File inputFile; 
  File outputFile;
  String userPassword;
  String ownerPassword;
  // A bit-field containing file permissions.
  int permissions = PDFWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING | PDFWriter.ALLOW_COPY;

  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFile);
  PdfEncryptor.encrypt(reader, new FileOutputStream(outputFile),
      ENCRYPTION_AES128, userPassword, ownerPassword, 
      permissions);
```

Here's the API for [PDFEncryptor](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfEncryptor.html) and [PDFWriter](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfWriter.html) (for the permissions).

Comment: Thanks Frederik. Can you also provide code to decrypt the encrypted file ?

Comment: For which version of iText is this viable?

Comment: It looks like iText has changed a bit since this answer was accepted. [Here's](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security/clone-encrypting-decrypting-pdfs) an example of how to encrypt and decrypt in iText 7. And [here](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.0/) is the updated location of the API docs.

Answer (score 10):

Using [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) (based on [Decrypt.java](http://pdfbox.apache.org/commandlineutilities/Decrypt.html) code) :

```java
PDDocument document = null;

try
{
    document = PDDocument.load( infile );

    if( document.isEncrypted() )
    {
        DecryptionMaterial decryptionMaterial = null;
        decryptionMaterial = new StandardDecryptionMaterial(password);
        document.openProtection(decryptionMaterial);
        AccessPermission ap = document.getCurrentAccessPermission();
        if(ap.isOwnerPermission())
        {
            document.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
            document.save( outfile );
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IOException(
            "Error: You are only allowed to decrypt a document with the owner password." );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.err.println( "Error: Document is not encrypted." );
    }
}
finally
{
    if( document != null )
    {
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible without password?

Comment: @AkashChavda I suppose that you are forced to pass the encrypted PDF password, else the encryption feature of PDF would be a nonsense ;) The code above simply use standard tools to decrypt the PDF.

Answer (score 5):

[iText](http://itextpdf.com/itext.php) supports encryption.