# itext pdf decryption using user password

Tags: java, pdf, encryption, itext

In itext, can we decrypt a pdf file using the user password that was used to encrypt the file?

I know decryption can be done using owner password. What I want to achieve is:

In my web application, keep pdf files in encrypted form. When the authorized user requests for a pdf file, then depending on the permissions (user's role), I send them a file with appropriate permissions - ALLOW_PRINTING, ALLOW_COPY etc.

What I am doing right now is I encrypt a file using OWNER and USER passwords and then decrypt it using OWNER password but then that file allows all actions - print, copy etc.

Please help.

Thanks,
Deepak

Comment: So you are storing the PDF on server disk using PDF encryption.  Then when the user requests the file, you want to remove the encryption, then re-encrypt using permissions?  Normally the *user* would be decrypting the file using the user password, so I'm not super clear on what you are going for.  Please post a snippet showing how you are doing your decryption and encryption.

Comment: "how can we decript a pdf file using the user password"?  Just type it into the UI when prompted?   I'm with Kevin on this one... not understanding the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, I follow this page:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/removing-password-from-pdf-on-linux/

And the tool qpdf works with only user password. Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

For decryption, you can use [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/), see my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9976481/535203

I give a sample code to decrypt a PDF given its password.