# unlock protected pdf files

Tags: java, pdf, batch-file

I need to process a large number of protected pdf files and edit them using a java program, but i don't have the passwords for these files. 
Is there any way to unlock this files with a batch?

I would like a windows command like tool or a java open source api.
What is the best solution ?

Comment: The best solution is to request support from the person that owns the file content -- that would probably be the person that password protected them.

Comment: As long as the PDFs only have an owner password and not a user password (you can still view them) then there is nothing encrypted in the files. The limitations are only imposed by the viewer applications, and the PDF is not really protected at all. You can just ignore the protection if you have your own editing app.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

are these pdf files asking for passwords to be opened, or **protection** consist in restrictions about copy, printing, modify, text extraction and so on?

if this is your case, you can try with

*qpdf*

- http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/

usage:

```
qpdf --decrypt file.pdf unlocked.pdf
```

and can be used in a batch operation *en masse*, in this way

```
for f in *.pdf ; do qpdf --decrypt $f ${f%%.pdf}unlocked.pdf; done
```

Comment: My pdf files are not asking for passwords.My restrictions are about copy, print, modify, i want a java library that do the same work as qpdf.

Comment: yes, this is the best free and Open Source alternative to PDFUnlock!

Answer (score 1):

For decryption, you can use [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/), see my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9976481/535203

I give a sample code to decrypt a PDF given its password.

There is also a binary to do that with PDFBox, check [the usage here](http://pdfbox.apache.org/commandlineutilities/Decrypt.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using iText library.

Here is a sample code :

```
        PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFile);
        PdfEncryptor.encrypt(reader, new FileOutputStream(outputFile), null,
              null, PdfWriter.ALLOW_ASSEMBLY | PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY
                  | PdfWriter.ALLOW_DEGRADED_PRINTING | PdfWriter.ALLOW_FILL_IN
                  | PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_ANNOTATIONS | PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_CONTENTS
                  | PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING | PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS, false);
```

*P.S. : use `unethicalreading` flag on your own risk*.

Comment: the new pdf still does not allow extracting pages