# How to join multiple PDF pages to a single Page

Tags: linux, pdf, merge, imagemagick, imposition

I have a PDF with 4 pages. I want to create another PDF where the pages are positioned one after the another (Vertical aligment) in a single page. Which commandline tool can be used for that?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2507766/841108)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No the questions are different. I want it in single page

Comment: Maybe `pfdunite` would do what you want....

Comment: `pdfunite` combines mutiple pdfs into one pdf with multiple pages, not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there are several ways to perform this task, one easier, one harder

---

## *The EASIER:* A MULTIVALENT.JAR WAY

Multivalent.jar is a stunning piece of free software able to perform many useful tasks on pdf

you can download from one of these links (the 2009 multivalent.jar build available on sourceforge has no more pdf tools inside)

- https://rg.to/file/c6bd7f31bf8885bcaa69b50ffab7e355
- you need to know the width and height of your pdf (in Linux you can use **pdfinfo**)

---

- assuming your **multipage pdf** is in ISO A4 size **(21x29.7cm)**, type:

---

> java -cp path..to/Multivalent.jar tool.pdf.Impose -dim 4x1 -paper
> 84x29.7cm input.pdf

---

this is the resulting page, composed by the 4 sequential pages stitched side by side together:

[image: 4_pdf_pages_appended_side_by_side]

- resulting pdf file
  http://ge.tt/98Kv4ce/v/0

explication:

> **-dim 4x1** means **number of columns for rows**
>
> **-paper 84x29.7cm** means **paper size** of your final imposed document containing the 4 pages joined side by side. obviously, since
> in your final pdf file, you will have 4 columns and only one row, you
> need to multiply by 4 the document witdh (21 cm)
>
> multivalent can accept, as unity input, also ***inches*** (**-paper
> 33.4x11.68in**) or ***postscript points*** (**-paper 2380x841pt**)

---

---

## THE *HARDER*: A LATEX WAY:

4_pdf_pages_appended_side_by_side

some years ago, Peter Flynn, in **comp.text.pdf** suggested, for a similar task,  a way to *appending* pdf pages **side by side** with the only help of LateX. If you are a LaTeXian, you can act as follows:

since you need to **append side by side** the four pages of your **single** *multipage* pdf, you will write a latex preamble, creating a new document like this:

assuming your pdf document has name **input.pdf** and its size is ISO A4, and you have this multipage pdf in your working folder, you will have

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0mm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\includepdfmerge[nup=1x4,landscape]{input.pdf,1,input.pdf,2,input.pdf,3,input.pdf,4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to a good version of Multivalent.  I strongly recommend getting it from http://ge.tt/#!/21OPDHX/v/4 as the other link redirects you to another domain and wants to download a .exe file.  It might be a self-extracting archive, but I suspect it will install other cruft as well.

Comment: many thanks; I replaced the ziddu link (even if using adblock and noscript you are able to download multivalent.jar without pain - the -exe is a  downloader tool for ziddu site but you are able to skip this and download only the Multivalent.jar file-) with rapidshare link; the best option I think could be add a torrent link in future

Comment: In the latex way, what should I do if I have 4 single-page pdf files?

Comment: Just use `\includepdfmerge[nup=1x4,landscape]{input1.pdf,1,input2.pdf,1,input3.pdf,1,input4.pdf,1}`

Answer (score 7):

If you use a Unix-like operating system, there is [pdfjam](https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam), which combines the Latex backend with an easy command:

`pdfjam --nup 1x4,landscape input.pdf`

EDIT: recently I had issues with pdfjam with that exact command. I had it working with:

`cat input.pdf | pdfjam -nup 1x4 -landscape –outfile out.pdf`

From [their docs](https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam/blob/master/README.md):

```
A potential drawback of pdfjam and other scripts based upon it is that any hyperlinks in the source PDF are lost
```

Comment: This fails if the PDF is password protected. I was able to remove this protection by specifing an empty password to PDFTK: `pdftk input.pdf input_pw "" output output.pdf`

Comment: @JPT Or, you start by unprotecting the PDF, assuming that protection is not relevant, as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749491/unlock-protected-pdf-files

Comment: in version 2.08 the proper command is `pdfjam --nup 1x4,landscape p1.pdf p2.pdf p3.pdf p4.pdf --outfile output.pdf`

Comment: FIY: "A potential drawback of pdfjam and other scripts based upon it is that any hyperlinks in the source PDF are lost"

Comment: @FFish i'll point it out, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I just did this with [CoherentPDF](https://community.coherentpdf.com/)

```
cpdf -impose-xy "0 4" in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

If the number of pages is unknown, set it to something bigger like

```
cpdf -impose-xy "0 99" in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

> The x value for -impose-xy may be set to zero to indicate an infinitely-wide page; the y value to indicate an infinitely-long one.
> In both cases, the pages in the input file **(*) are assumed to be of the same dimensions.**

More options can be explored in the excellent manual:
https://www.coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual/cpdfmanualch9.html#x13-860009.2

(*) In my case first I had to scale the last page to fit the dimensions of the other pages, followed by the imposing.

```
cpdf \
-scale-to-fit "768pt 1024pt" -top 0 in.pdf end \
AND \
-impose-xy "99 0" in.pdf \
-o out.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem. I needed to develop a solution to preprocess a PDF to better identify the tables using the [`tabula-py`](https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/) package. Here's the step-by-step solution to my problem:

1. Remove header and footer from all `n` pages;
2. Split the PDF into `n` files containing 1 single page each;
3. Crop the single page from the `n` files according to its bounding box;
4. Merge the `n` files into 1 single PDF containing 1 page, keeping the order;
5. Read and preprocess tables from text based PDF using `tabula-py`.

In my case, **step 3** of the process can generate files with different dimensions. When using the `pdfjam` command I had problems aligning the pages in **step 4**, even using the [`--pagetemplate`](https://texdoc.org/serve/pdfpages.pdf/0) parameter. For me the vertical alignment was the worst.

Fortunately, I was able to solve this page alignment problem using a LaTeX based approach. Here is the base source code I used -- put all files in the same directory.

**The answer to this post's question is in the "Shell Script" section, starting from the line "Merging the 'n' pages into a single one using LaTeX..."**.

#### Requirements:

I tested this solution using the Debian linux distro. To work on Windows, you can [install Debian via WSL](https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-debian-on-windows-wsl/), for example. Assuming you are using Debian or Ubuntu, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install texlive-extra-utils texlive-latex-extra poppler-utils ghostscript default-jdk -y
```

As a result of PDF preprocessing, the final file may have reduced dimensions, especially in width. Even though it is vectorized, reducing the size of the PDF has a negative impact on the quality of extracting tables using the `tabula-py` tool.

To increase the size of the final PDF file, keeping the aspect ratio, we can use the [`cpdf`](https://community.coherentpdf.com/) tool. In the case of using a Linux distro, just copy the [binary file](https://github.com/coherentgraphics/cpdf-binaries) to the same directory as the Shell script. Then give the binary file execute permission:

```
chmod +x cpdf
```

#### LaTeX template:

Create a file named `pdf_merge_template.tex` with the following content:

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\centering<PDF-PAGES>

\end{document}
```

#### Shell script:

Create a file named `pdf-preprocessing.sh` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

# References
# ----------
# [PDF preprocessing] https://stackoverflow.com/a/71802078/16109419

PDF_MERGE_TEMPLATE_FILENAME="pdf_merge_template.tex"
PDF_MERGE_TEMPLATE_PAGES_MACRO="<PDF-PAGES>"
CPDF_FILENAME="cpdf"  # Binary file of "Coherent PDF" tool.

INPUT_FILEPATH=$1
OUTPUT_FILEPATH=$2

if [ "$#" -eq  "2" ]; then
    echo "Starting PDF preprocessing..."
else
    echo "ERROR: Wrong arguments ('INPUT_FILEPATH', 'OUTPUT_FILEPATH')!"
    exit
fi

TEMP_DIR_PATH=$(mktemp -d)
echo "Setting up working directory: ${TEMP_DIR_PATH}"

THIS_FILENAME=$(readlink -f "$0")
THIS_DIR=$(dirname "$THIS_FILENAME")
PDF_MERGE_TEMPLATE_PATH="${THIS_DIR}/${PDF_MERGE_TEMPLATE_FILENAME}"
CPDF_BIN_PATH="${THIS_DIR}/${CPDF_FILENAME}"

echo "Removing header and footer from all pages..."

# Removing header and footer from PDF pages based on margin settings (e.g., '5 -75 5 -25'):
pdfcrop --margins '5 -75 5 -25' "${INPUT_FILEPATH}" "${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/input-tmp.pdf"

# Deleting the textual content of the cut parts:
pdftocairo "${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/input-tmp.pdf" "${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/input.pdf" -pdf

# Counting the number of pages from PDF:
NUM_PAGES=$(pdfinfo "${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/input.pdf" | awk '/^Pages:/ {print $2}')
REL_PAGE_WIDTH=$(python -c "print(1 / ${NUM_PAGES})")
PAGES_LIST=""

echo "Cropping each page based on its specific bounding box..."
for i in $(seq 1 $NUM_PAGES)
do
    # Splitting current page:
    pdfjam "${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/input.pdf" $i --outfile "${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/page_${i}-tmp.pdf"

    # Fetching bounding box of current page:
    PAGE_WIDTH=$(pdfinfo "${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/page_${i}-tmp.pdf" | awk '/^Page size:/ {print $3}')
    BBOX=$(gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=bbox "${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/page_${i}-tmp.pdf" 2>&1 | awk '/^%%HiResBoundingBox:/ {print 0 " " $3 " " '${PAGE_WIDTH}' " " $5}')

    # Removing content out of current page's bounding box:
    PAGE_FILENAME="page_${i}"
    PDF_FILEPATH="${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/${PAGE_FILENAME}.pdf"
    PS_FILEPATH="${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/${PAGE_FILENAME}.ps"
    gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -sOutputFile=$PDF_FILEPATH -c "[/CropBox [${BBOX}] /PAGES pdfmark" -f "${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/page_${i}-tmp.pdf"

    PAGES_LIST="${PAGES_LIST}\n    \\\includegraphics[width=${REL_PAGE_WIDTH}\\\textwidth]{${PDF_FILEPATH}} \\\\\\\ \\\vspace{-0.03cm}"
done

echo "Merging the 'n' pages into a single one using LaTeX..."
cp $PDF_MERGE_TEMPLATE_PATH "${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/merged.tex"
sed -i "s#${PDF_MERGE_TEMPLATE_PAGES_MACRO}#${PAGES_LIST}#g" "${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/merged.tex"
latex -halt-on-error -output-directory $TEMP_DIR_PATH "${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/merged.tex"
dvipdfm "${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/merged.dvi" -o "${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/merged.pdf"

echo "Finalizing the PDF and sending a copy to the destination directory..."

# Adding margins to the final PDF:
pdfcrop --margins 5 "${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/merged.pdf" "${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/output-tmp.pdf"

# Enlargement of the final PDF file to extract tables correctly using the "tabula-py" tool:
$CPDF_BIN_PATH -scale-page "10 10" "${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/output-tmp.pdf" -o "${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/output.pdf"

# Copying the pre-processed PDF file to the output path:
cp "${TEMP_DIR_PATH}/output.pdf" "${OUTPUT_FILEPATH}"

echo "Deleting temp files..."
rm -rf "${TEMP_DIR_PATH}"
```

Give execution permission to the script using the following command:

```
chmod +x pdf-preprocessing.sh
```

#### Usage examples:

To preprocess a file called `example.pdf`, simply run the following command:

```
sh pdf-preprocessing.sh example.pdf preprocessed-example.pdf
```

Edit the script parameters as per your case. The header and footer coordinates, for example, will depend on the template of your files. Feel free to suggest improvements and simplifications.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use [`pdfxup`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfxup).
`-o` .. Outfile
`-x` .. n columns per page
`-y` .. n lines per page
`-fw 0` .. would remove the frame around the pages

```
pdfxup -o out.pdf -x 4 -y 1 input.pdf
```

[image: Image with pages 1,2,3,4 side by side]

`-l` .. landscape-mode

```
pdfxup -o out.pdf -x 1 -y 4 -l 0 input.pdf
```

[image: Image with pages 1,2,3,4 under each other]

Making a 2x2 Page row wise.

```
pdfxup -o out.pdf -x 2 -y 2 -l 0 input.pdf
```

[image: Image pages 2x2 row wise]

Making a 2x2 Page col wise.

```
pdfxup -o out.pdf -x 2 -y 2 -l 0 -col input.pdf
```

[image: Image pages 2x2 col wise]

---

Or using [`pdfjam`](https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam).

```
pdfjam --outfile out.pdf --nup 4x1 --landscape input.pdf
```

[image: Image with pages 1,2,3,4 side by side]

```
pdfjam --outfile out.pdf --nup 1x4 input.pdf
```

[image: Image with pages 1,2,3,4 under each other]

```
pdfjam --outfile out.pdf --nup 2x2 input.pdf
```

[image: Image pages 2x2 row wise]

```
pdfjam --outfile out.pdf --nup 2x2 --column true input.pdf
```

[image: Image pages 2x2 col wise]

---

Latex code to create the 4 pdf pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{\textheight}{\textheight}
\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont
\centering
1\\2\\3\\4
\end{document}
```

The pdf outputs are converted to png using

```
pdftoppm -singlefile -scale-to 300 out.pdf out -png
```