# Build a PDF file from parts of another

Tags: pdf, editor, command-line-interface, ghostscript

I have a template for a Hipster PDA (you remember those, don't you?) that shows four copies of the same card on one page then four copies of the next card on the next, and so forth. I would like to rearrange things so that each page only has one copy of each card, so I can print four distinct cards to a page, without wasting a lot of paper. I did something vaguely similar to this years ago, but that involved hand editing a lot of Postscript and took forever to do. I would like some sort of command-line solution that would cut a different quadrant from each page and then paste four them onto a single new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try and get what you want in two steps:

- Setup CropBox for each of the pages so that only one copy of a card lays within the CropBox.
- Use a PDF imposition software to make new pages from 4 "old" ones

For the latter you could try [Multivalent Impose](http://multivalent.sourceforge.net/Tools/pdf/Impose.html) tool.

Comment: your answer is everything I wanted, except that the Multivalent Impose tool doesn't seem to work.  I downloaded the latest Multivalent20091027.jar, but it doesn't seem to have the Impose tool included.

C:\Users\dentos>java -classpath Downloads\Multivalent20091027.jar tool.pdf.Impose
Error: Could not find or load main class tool.pdf.Impose

Comment: `C:\Users\dentos>java -classpath Downloads\Multivalent20091027.jar tool.pdf.Impose`
`Error: Could not find or load main class tool.pdf.Impose`

Comment: @samwyse I am sorry about Multivalent. Probably should have tried it myself before recommending. I can only recommend you to try solutions for these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16119560/249690 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2507766/249690